# "Composition" property in cooperative game theory?

Tags: game-theory

I am trying to find a property which can help to analyse the composition of a cost/profit division and which allocation rules (e.g., Shapley value or nucleolus) would satisfy it.

In short, the idea is that if I divide a player into more players (subplayer), they should still get the same as the original player (the sum of the profit/cost of the subplayers is equal to the one of the original player).
The characteristic function and the profit/cost for all the other players should remain the same as well.

I am sure that someone has studied this before. So far I looked at different versions of monotonicity but they do not seem to reflect what I am looking for.

The simple option would be to divide the problem in two different games (e.g., based on the profit/cost of the player make a game for the sub players to see how to divide it), but I think that if you plug the subplayers instead of the original player they should still get the same as the original player.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that you mean additivity, that is, a solution $\sigma$ is additive, if $\sigma(v_1+v_2)=\sigma(v_1)+\sigma(v_2)$ holds, whereas $v_1,v_2$ are Tu-games. The Shapley value satisfies this property, however, the (pre-)nucleolus not.

Comment: I need to think about it but I am not sure whether additivity is what I am after. 

Game one: v(1)=3, v(2)= 2, v(12)=8. Game two, where player 2 is split into players 2A and 2B: w(1)=3, w(2A)=1, w(2B)=1, w(1,2A)=5, w(1,2B)=5, w(2A,2B)=2, w(1,2A,2B)=8. 

Would additivity help to grant the same share to player 1 in both games? That is, would 2A and 2B divide the share of player 2?
I will look at it. Thanks :)

Comment: This sounds that you are looking on the consistency of a solution like the reduced game property (RGP), (Hart and Mas-Colell)-RGP, or converse reduced game property (CRGP). These concepts are based on a properly defined reduced game (sub-game). The Shapley value satisfies HM-RGP, the pre-nucleolus RGP, and the pre-kernel RGP and CRGP.

Comment: Great pointer! I will look at it :)